# Workaround mysterious bug, involving minitoc, twocolumns, and abstract

Tags: two-column, minitoc

In the following MWE, the mini table of contents of Section 1, comes out to be of Section 2, while Section 2 is missing its mini table of contents.

The combination of two components creates the problem:

1. the `abstract` environment
2. the `twocolumn` option to the `article` class

If one of these is commented out, the output comes out right.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\dosecttoc
\begin{document}

 % Comment out to get minitoc do the right thing
\begin{abstract}and god said let there be light and there was light\end{abstract}
    \tableofcontents
\section{Pentateuch}
\secttoc

\subsection{Genesis}
In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
\subsection{Exodus}
Now these are the names of the children of Israel, which came into Egypt; every man and his household came with Jacob.
\subsection{Leviticus}
And the Lord called unto Moses, and spake unto him out of the tabernacle of the congregation, saying,
\subsection{Numbers}
And the Lord spake unto Moses in the wilderness of Sinai, in the tabernacle of the congregation, on the first day of the second month, in the second year after they were come out of the land of Egypt, saying,
\subsection{Deuteronomy}
These be the words which Moses spake unto all Israel on this side Jordan in the wilderness, in the plain over against the Red sea, between Paran, and Tophel, and Laban, and Hazeroth, and Dizahab.

\section{Gospels}
    \secttoc

\subsection{Matthew}
The book of the generation of Jesus Christ, the son of David, the son of Abraham.
\subsection{Mark}
The beginning of the gospel of Jesus Christ, the Son of God;
\subsection{Luke}
 Forasmuch as many have taken in hand to set forth in order a declaration of those things which are most surely believed among us,
\subsection{John}
In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.

\end{document}
```

Output demonstrating the bug to be worked around
[image: Output of the above]

Output with the `abstract` line commented out
[image: Output with the <code>abstract</code> line commented out]

Single column version:
[image: Single column version]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In two column mode `abstract` inserts a `\section*{abstractname}` and this disturbs the counter of `minitoc`. You can decrement the counter:

```
\begin{abstract}
\decrementstc
and god said let there be light and there was light
\end{abstract}
```

(It looks like a bug to me, but the description regarding starred sections in the minitoc documentation is rather confusing.)